# Celery dies with DBPageNotFoundError

Tags: python, celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I have 3 machines with celery workers and rabbitmq as a broker, one worker is running with beat flag, all of this is managed by supervisor, and sometimes celery dies with such error. 
This error appears only on beat worker, but when it appears, workers on all machines dies.
(celery==3.1.12, kombu==3.0.20)

```
[2014-07-05 08:37:04,297: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://user:**@192.168.15.106:5672//
[2014-07-05 08:37:04,311: ERROR/Beat] Process Beat
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 292, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 527, in run
self.service.start(embedded_process=True)
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 453, in start
humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 322, in __get__
value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 491, in scheduler
return self.get_scheduler()
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 486, in get_scheduler
lazy=lazy)
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 53, in instantiate
return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 357, in __init__
Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 184, in __init__
self.setup_schedule()
File "/var/projects/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 376, in setup_schedule
self._store['entries']
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shelve.py", line 121, in __getitem__
f = StringIO(self.dict[key])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in __getitem__
return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/dbutils.py", line 68, in DeadlockWrap
return function(*_args, **_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 270, in <lambda>
return _DeadlockWrap(lambda: self.db[key])  # self.db[key]
DBPageNotFoundError: (-30985, 'DB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found')
```

Comment: Try starting beat as standalone instead of using -B, some -db implementations does not like being in a process forked from a python process.

Comment: @asksol For me the file gets corrupted roughly every 2 months :( I wonder if anybody investigated the problem deeper...

Answer (score 12):

I've ran into this issue and the cause was a corrupted db file (usually named "celerybeat-schedule").
Solution would be to delete the existing db file and restart the process.

Relavent:bsddb.db.DBPageNotFoundError
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-October/554552.html

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove some temp files in the `/tmp` directory.  One was named `celeryd-<NAME_OF_WORKER>-state` and also `celeryd-<NAME_OF_WORKER>-state-renamed`.  After removing those and I was able to restart my affected worker.